# Hide animation result on android

Tags: animation, android

I use translate animation to hide a bottom layout in an activity.

```
translate>
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%"
    android:duration="300">
</translate>

hideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bottom_bar_animation);
imageTitleLayout.startAnimation(hideAnimation);
```

The activity has

```
android:configChanges="orientation".
```

So if my view hides in landscape mode it just goes lower the screen and is not shown.
But when I change the orientation of the device to portrait I can see the bottom layout near the center of the screen.
The .setVisibility(View.GONE) doesn't work because we see not the view, but the result of the animation.

The way to hide the view is:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(1);

    imageTitleLayout.startAnimation(fadeOut);
}
```

But the code looks very ugly.
Is there a better way to hide the result of an animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the View.clearAnimation() method.

Basically just call `View.clearAnimation()` to get rid of the animation result image.

Comment: You can answer your own question, but more detail about how this is an answer would help.